# Why is my lisp function returning 'NIL'

Tags: list, lisp, common-lisp, clisp

I am writing a lisp function, that will determine if a word is a palindrome without using the 'reverse' function. I am fairly new to lisp and I am still trying to grasp the concept. The function is returning `NIL` every time I test a palindrome, any ideas why?

My function I have came up with.

```
(defun palindromep (list)
    (cond
        ((null list)t)
        (t
            (and (equal (first list) (first (rest list)))
                (palindromep (butlast (rest list)))))))
```

Code revision

```
(defun palindromep (list)
    (cond
        ((null list)t)
        (t
            (and (equal (first list) (first(last list)))
                (palindromep (butlast(rest list)))))))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How I see it it seems to work an a special set of palindromes where there are even number of elements of the same kind.

You'll need to return `t` for one element list. ie. `(null (cdr list))`.

The check you have checks if the two first elements are the same instead if the first and the last elements are the same.

**EDIT**

The best way to do this with recursion and without using reverse that I can think of is this way:

```
(defun palindromep (list)
  (labels ((aux (history tortoise hare)
             (cond ((null hare) (equal tortoise history))
                   ((null (cdr hare)) (equal (cdr tortoise) history))
                   (t (aux (cons (car tortoise) history)
                           (cdr tortoise)
                           (cddr hare))))))
    (aux '() list list)))
```

How it works is by having an extra cursor `hare` that iterates twice the distance as the `tortoise` and at the same time the seen element is accumulated in `history`. Since `cons` makes lists from end to beginning the history is all the seen elements in reverse and thus should match the end when you have reached the middle. When either `cdr` or `cddr` of hare is null you are at the middle and can determine palindrome by an easy comparison.

**EDIT 2**

If you move the helper out it's easier to trace and see what is happening:

```
(defun aux (history tortoise hare)
  (cond ((null hare) (equal tortoise history))
        ((null (cdr hare)) (equal (cdr tortoise) history))
        (t (aux (cons (car tortoise) history)
                (cdr tortoise)
                (cddr hare)))))

(defun palindromep (list)
  ;; just calls helper
  (aux '() list list))

;; trace the helper
(trace aux)
(trace equal) ; you might need to follow instructions to unlock

(palindromep '(1 2 3 3 2 1))
  0: (AUX NIL (1 2 3 3 2 1) (1 2 3 3 2 1))
    1: (AUX (1) (2 3 3 2 1) (3 3 2 1))
      2: (AUX (2 1) (3 3 2 1) (2 1))
        3: (AUX (3 2 1) (3 2 1) NIL)
          4: (EQUAL (3 2 1) (3 2 1))
          4: EQUAL returned T
        3: AUX returned T
      2: AUX returned T
    1: AUX returned T
  0: AUX returned T
==> T

(palindromep '(1 2 3 4 5 6))
  0: (AUX NIL (1 2 3 4 5 6) (1 2 3 4 5 6))
    1: (AUX (1) (2 3 4 5 6) (3 4 5 6))
      2: (AUX (2 1) (3 4 5 6) (5 6))
        3: (AUX (3 2 1) (4 5 6) NIL)
          4: (EQUAL (4 5 6) (3 2 1))
          4: EQUAL returned NIL
        3: AUX returned NIL
      2: AUX returned NIL
    1: AUX returned NIL
  0: AUX returned NIL
==> NIL
```

Comment: I revised my code and now it is telling me every thing i enter is a palindrome, any suggestions?

Comment: @RileyThomas Thats because the argument to the recursion was correct, but not anymore. THe recursion is no longer done only when the first element macthes but always going until you hit the base case, the empty list. Also the test for one element list should have been together with the test for empty list. `(or a b)` or as separate terms in the `cond`. How it is now it's done always in the default case and not as a tail expression.

Comment: the revision I made seems to work now. Any suggestion on how I could rewrite the last line of my function so that it still does the same thing?

Comment: @RileyThomas It seems like the default case is ok. You need to check for `(or (null list) (null (cdr  list)))` instead of just `(null list)` and it will work for odd element palindromes as well. Since you only have two terms if would work just as well with `if`

Comment: ok I will include that, is there another way I could say `(palindromep (butlast(rest list))` ?

Comment: @RileyThomas Not really. `butlast` isn't really a very effiecent thing since it needs to make a new list until it has the last `cons`. See my edit for my take on the function that uses ideas from a cycle detection algorithm.

Comment: I think I understand what this function is doing, I might have a few holes in my theory. You have created a function `palindromep` that has three helper functions `history, tortoise, hare` I believe that hare and tortoise check the elements of the list but at different iterations? `history` will serve as the list `tortoise` and `hare` check? I am a bit confused on the conditions. Is it saying "check to see if `hare` is null, if not `tortoise equals history`? Then if the rest of `cdr` hare is null the rest of `cdr` tortoise equals `history` ?

Comment: @RileyThomas Not quite. I have one helper function `aux` it takes three arguments `history`, `tortoise` and `hare` and it changes them on recursive tail calls such that when the base case hit `history` and `tortoise` should be the same when adjusted for odd/even lengths. When you pass it `(1 2 2 1)` and `hare` is `nil` after 2 iterations then `tortoise` is `(2 1)` and `history` is the elements before in reverse, thus `(2 1)`. For odd element like `(1 2 3 2 1)` `history` is the same but `tortoise` is `(3 2 1)`

Comment: @RileyThomas you can actually move the helper out as a `defun` and call it from the other one amd `trace` the helper and you'll see the arguments change.

Comment: After the condition is it saying, if `true`, or is it saying while `true` call the function `aux` and then cons takes the first element from `tortoise` and `history` with the rest of `tortoise` and the rest of `hare` to make a list? And then by calling `aux` you are just returning the final list?

Comment: @RileyThomas a `cond` is never a while,  but it recurs to the helper and thus behaves like a loop.  The idea is to move elements from `tortoise` to`history` until you are at the half of the list. Since `hare` moves twice as fast it indicates when `tortoise` is halfway.